# VBScript ADODB.Recordset error '800a0cc1' when trying to read varchar2(4000 byte)

Tags: oracle, vbscript

When I try to retrieve the value of a field from Oracle Db (field type varchar2(4000 byte)) and display it in html table I get the error;

> ADODB.Recordset 800a0cc1

The query is:

```
<% set Rs = oConn.Execute("SELECT DISTINCT IV.CATEG,IV.CATEG_NAME, IV.SEQ_NUM,
  IV.ACTIVE_FLG, IV.RUS FROM TBL_SBL_VIEW_IVR_DIR iv WHERE IV.CATEG_NAME=21")%>

<td><%=(Rs("IV.RUS"))%></td>                        

Rs.Close
Set oConn = Nothing
%>
```

The error occurs in this line:

```
<td><%=(Rs("IV.RUS"))%></td>
```

I'm sure that the record in DB exists, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Guessing it might be a typo but you're missing `<%` before `Rs.Close`.

Comment: oh,it is a typo when i wrote this post...

Comment: @Евгений was the typo the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<td><%=(Rs("RUS"))%></td>
```

If that doesn't work, and you can debug your script, get the names of the fields by iterating through it.

```
For Each f in Rs.Fields
    Wscript.Echo f.Name
Next
```

If that doesn't help either, try accessing the index of the item in the recordset. Be cautious doing this because if your query changed it can change this index.

```
<td><%=(Rs.Fields(4))%></td>
```

Edit:
Here's a bit more information:
[ADO RecordSet Field Object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms676678(v=vs.85).aspx)

Specifically, "The **identifier of the column** from the data source is represented by the Name property of the Field."

So the name of the Field is the name of the column. In your example, your column name will be `RUS` *not* `IV.RUS`.